# repeating table not auto-sizing correctly

Tags: infopath

This repeating table seems to be taking up too much room. I have set it and the table it is nested in to auto-size height and have clicked and dragged the bottom of the section it is at the top to get it back to minimum size, but it still takes up this much room.

Examples:

In designer view my form looks like this:

[image: designer]

In the filter it expands to this size:

[image]

can this be shrunk back down? It was all the correct size before adding the table.

PS: can I use a repeating section to attach multiple files like this? They seem simpler, but I was unable to figure it out.